# cannot import name 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler

Tags: tensorflow, import, importerror, trace, tensorboard

My enviorment was working fine, getting back to it after a while and when I try to run tensorboard I face this error:

> cannot import name 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler

I have these packages in my conda env tfgpu220:
spyder                        5.3.0
spyder-kernels                2.3.0
tensorboard                   2.2.2
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow-gpu                2.2.0
tensorflow-gpu-estimator      2.2.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.25.0
termcolor                     1.1.0
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.2.2
tf-estimator-nightly          2.8.0.dev2021122109

Any help, Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade the Tensorflow version and then import trace.

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

Use the following statement to import trace.

```
from tf.profiler.experimental import Trace
```